# How to add multiple patterns to the matcher in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I want to know how can I add different patterns to the matcher. What I want is to do something like this

```
matcher.add("COUNTRIES",None,*patterncountry)
matcher.add("ZONES",None,*patternzones)
matcher.add("DAYS",None,patterndays)
```

So now I have 3 patterns. How can this be achive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SpaCy, the the `Matcher` lets you match sequences based on lists of token descriptions while the `PhraseMatcher` lets you efficiently match large terminology lists. In your case the `PhraseMatcher` would be more appropriate to use.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

countries = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['Canada', 'United States', 'Mexico']]
days = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                                        'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']]

phrase_matcher.add("COUNTRIES",None, *countries)
phrase_matcher.add("DAYS",None, *days)


text = 'On Monday I travelled to Canada.'
doc = nlp(text)
matches = phrase_matcher(doc)
```

Comment: how do i get the start and end index of the match keyword in the original sentence ?

Comment: The matcher returns a list of (match_id, start, end) tuples.

Comment: Is there a way to make the process of iterating over phrase 'list' more efficient? Right now nlp.make_doc() and phrase_matcher.add() functions are taking a lot of time when I am iterating over product list of my ecommerce website. I have got around 50 categories of the products and 15 products in each category on an average. And each time I do a little update in my product list, it takes around 30 minutes to update my matcher again! Any help will be much appreciated.